# php7.0-dbg Installed and don't work

Tags: php, installation, phpdbg

I installed php7.0-dbg using ppa:ondrej/ph into my ubuntu LTS 14.04. After the installation I tryed run `phpdbg` command, but I received the message:

```
phpdbg: command not found
```

Did I understand wrong? What is that package?

My `dpkg -l php7.0`*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From documentation, you can start the debugger by typing in this command:

```
$ gdb
```

And run:

```
> run path_to_php_script.php
```

Finally to see the back trace log:

```
> bt
```